# Should I use GNU GPL or CC-0 to distribute scripts?

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation

I want to add a copyright disclaimer in all my **code/scripts** (i.e. not software), which I share in my website. These are for many languages, like Matlab, R, Stata, Julia, etc.

Which license should I use? GNU GPL or CC-0?

(The GNU GPL license seems to be the standard, but it mentions the word "software". I don't think a script classifies as software, and so it feels a bit odd to have it there.)

Comment: Are you OK or not with someone taking your stuff and modifying it and distributing it in some obfuscated form without showing the source to anyone? We can't answer if you don't tell us.

Comment: Yes, that is fine for me. Does that mean a CC0 license is better?

Comment: Yes, if that's fine for you, then choose CC0, it allows people to do that.

Answer (score 3):

From the Wiktionary definition of software:

> Encoded computer instructions, usually modifiable (unless stored in some form of unalterable memory such as ROM).

So yes, scripts obviously classify as software.

Now, if the only difference to you between GPL and CC-0 is the one you described, then you have **a lot** to learn.

In short, GPL used indeed to be the standard. It is not really *the* standard anymore, just one of the most common choices. MIT is also a very common choice. These two licenses are very different in what they allow, with MIT one of the most permissive and GPL one of the most restrictive. Apache 2.0 is also a common choice (see some recommendations here: http://choosealicense.com/).

For short scripts, GPL is generally not recommended (even by the FSF):

> **What if the work is not very long? [(#WhatIfWorkIsShort)](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#WhatIfWorkIsShort)**
>
> If a whole software package contains very little code—less than 300 lines is the benchmark we use—you may as well use a lax permissive license for it, rather than a copyleft license like the GNU GPL. (Unless, that is, the code is specially important.) We recommend the Apache License 2.0 for such cases.

My preference for very short scripts goes to <strike>CC-0</strike> [the Unlicense](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/unlicense/) because I want people to be able to reuse them in every way they want, without needing to attribute me. <strike>If this is also what you want, then go ahead and apply CC-0 to your work as detailed here: https://creativecommons.org/choose/zero/</strike>

EDIT: as discussed in the comments, CC0 is not recommended for software by the FSF and the OSI. The Unlicense is a popular and recommended alternative.

Comment: Creative Commons [suggests against using any Creative Commons license for software](https://creativecommons.org/faq/), which would include the CC0. One reason for this is patent issues. Instead, using a license like the Zero Clause BSD license would allow anyone to use the source code without attribution, while avoiding any issues with releasing software under the CC0.

Comment: Actually, the FAQ entry you are referring to (https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software) explicitly mentions that CC0 is "acceptable for software". However, like you said, there are issues with CC0 for software, and both the OSI and the FSF discourage its use for software (https://opensource.org/faq/#cc-zero, https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#CC0). The Unlicense is an OSI-approved / FSF-approved alternative. 0BSD is not as well-known, so I would not recommend it. It is OSI-approved, but it's not (yet?) FSF-approved.

Comment: I'm surprised the Unlicense is approved by both the OSI and the FSF, considering [its supposed issues with not being international](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147111/what-is-wrong-with-the-unlicense), though maybe the OSI and the FSF think it actually is valid internationally.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Reading the comments carefully also makes you learn that it was eventually approved by the OSI, although a well-known member of this site tried to argue against: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147111/what-is-wrong-with-the-unlicense. Currently, I would say that the Unlicense is probably safer to use than 0BSD because it is more widely used and recognized (and because of the issues of CC0 for software) and that 0BSD could suffer from the same issues. But this could change in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! After doing more research, the argument that the Unlicense is "unprofessional" doesn't seem to hold up, especially with the approval by the OSI and FSF. So I'm in agreement too that it is the best to use for granting software to the public domain.

Answer (score 1):

CC by 0 means Creative Commons which any person can use/share/edit the script without providing a link (attribution) to you. Whereas with the GNU GPL it is not the case.

If you want the credit, you can use CC-BY-SA or MIT. Many libraries like jQuery use MIT License.

Comment: Why is GNU GPL not the case? Which is the difference?

Comment: @luchonacho CC0 allows reuse without attribution. The GPL requires attribution.